# Find speed and distance given two conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Here is my attempt:

Let the distance between the two towns be x km,

and let the speed of the train be y km/h.

So, $\frac{x}{y}=t$, $\frac{x}{y+5}=t-\frac{2}{5}$, $
\frac{x}{y-4}=t+\frac{2}{5}$

I am stuck here (am I on the right track?), please help with a hint 
on how to proceed. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: You are on the right track. You now have three equations and three unknowns. Make some substitutions and you can solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

By using the property that $x=ty$, we have

$$x = (t-\frac25) ( y+5)=ty-\frac25y+5t-2=x-\frac25y+5t-2$$

which implies that

$$0=-\frac25y+5t-2$$

which is a linear equation. Can you use the same trick on the last equation to obtain another linear equation in $t$ and $y$ and solve the simultaneous equations?

Comment: thanks, I will attempt using this method, is there an easier approach?